# DynamicComponentLoader - how to avoid the redundant wrapper element?

Tags: angular

Following the DynamicComponentLoader documentation at [DynamicComponentLoader-class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html). I understand that a wrapper element must be created. In the example below, the wrapper element is "child-component".

```
   @Component({
      selector: 'child-component',
      template: 'Child'
    })
    class ChildComponent {
    }
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: 'Parent'
    })
    class MyApp {
      constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {
        dcl.loadNextToLocation(ChildComponent, elementRef);
      }
    }
    bootstrap(MyApp);
```

Resulting DOM:

```
    <my-app>Parent</my-app>
    <child-component>Child</child-component>
```

My Target:

```
    <my-app>Parent</my-app>
    Child
```

I wrote my own code to handle it

```
loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent, cmp, 'child').then(function(ref) {
    var elem = ref.location.nativeElement;
    ref.instance._nativeElement = elem.firstElementChild; // this._nativeElement instead of this.elementRef.nativeElement
    if (elem.parentNode && elem.firstElementChild)
        elem.parentNode.replaceChild(elem.firstElementChild, elem);
    else
        console.log('can not delete Redundent ', elem);
})
```

My "rough" code does the work, but it does not seem to be aligned with ng2 architecture.
Any idea for a better solution to avoid the wrapper element?

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: I need to create components dynamically based on a JSON spec. Yet, I want to keep the DOM structure clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loadAsRoot()` function to achieve your requirements

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: 'Child'
})
class ChildComponent {
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 'Parent'
})
class MyApp {
  constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    this.dcl.loadAsRoot(ChildComponent, "child-component", this.injector)
  }
}
bootstrap(MyApp);
```

Comment: loadAsRoot will put it under the **main DOM Document**. I need it locally.